# Where is datastore and why my data is gone when I shut down the computer

Tags: python, google-app-engine

When I shut down my computer my data is gone. I researched and read some problems like mine and the solution is that : 
"""Maybe the default data store path is in a /tmp directory that's being deleted on shutdown? You can manually set the path with the --datastore_path flag in dev_appserver.py. """

and I do the same I write this to console

```
dev_appserver.py --datastore_path=/tmp/newapp_datastore /home/newapp
```

but it didnt work. 
When I shut down computer I couldnt display in my main page but there is a folder in tmp and there are data files in this folder. Please can you tell me :
1-Why my data is gone when I shut-down computer?And what can I do?
2-Where is my data in my computer?how can I learn?

Answer (score 3):

Specify a datastore path that is not in `/tmp`. By default `/tmp` is a memory based filesystem and will therefore be cleared on each reboot.

For instance:

```
dev_appserver.py --datastore_path=/home/newapp_datastore /home/newapp
```

Comment: @ReneeWalker Use like this `dev_appserver.py --datastore_path=/home/newapp_datastore /home/newapp`

Comment: /tmp will always be cleared on reboot, see edit above for example

Comment: I undertood already tmp is always be cleared, but I couldnt figure out how can I change the path. Thanks Nijin it worked, but data is still gone :((( why my data is lost ?

Comment: Because the file that the dev_appserver used for your local data store was deleted on reboot.

Comment: What did you change the path to?